# Celery получение объекта из БД

Tags: python, django, celery

У модели есть post_save сигнал

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
def update_history(instance, **kwargs):
    update_history_task.delay(instance.id)

def update_history_task(project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    create_history_record(project)
```

Если задача стартует после обновления записи, то все работает так как положено.
Если задача стартует после того как запись создана, то в задаче я получаю исключение `DoesNotExist`.
Предполагаю это происходит по той причине, что celery задача начинается раньше чем заканчивается запись в БД.
Как проконтролировать чтобы задание начиналось после того, как запись появится в БД?

Comment: [Описание того как надо это делать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit)

Answer (score -1):

можно сделать отложенный запуск задачи

```
update_history_task.apply_async(instance.id, countdown=1)
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?